# IdentityServer4 OIDC request object support

Tags: identityserver4

The OIDC specification includes Request Object JWT parameter (signed JWT) that can be passed to the authorize request, see [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#JWTRequests). Quote:

> OpenID Connect defines the following Authorization Request parameters to enable Authentication Requests to be signed and optionally encrypted:
>
> request
> OPTIONAL. This parameter enables OpenID Connect requests to be passed in a single, self-contained parameter and to be optionally signed and/or encrypted. The parameter value is a Request Object value, as specified in Section 6.1. It represents the request as a JWT whose Claims are the request parameters.

IdentityServer4 documentation does not mention it, see [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html).

Question: Does IdentityServer4 support this parameter? If not, what would the best way be to extend IdentityServer4 to support it (e.g. which class should be overridden, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that there is already a feature request for this on the [IdentityServer4 github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/594).

So, IdentityServer4 does not support Request Object (signed request) at present.